# Javascript is this a vaild call?

Tags: javascript

I know that when getting `return` data from `webmethods` in javascript this code is valid, but how about if it is a return from another js method?

The `alert` is never ran so I am thinking no, but I want to make sure it is this and not other code throwing the error:

```
function previousWinner() {
    //Webservice call
    services.isUserAWinner(ID, events, function (response) {
           //Code

            //Return
            return true;
        }
        //Return
        return false;
    });
}
```

And later in my code I call this

```
  previousWinner(function (response) {
        alert(response);
        //Check to see if user is a winner
        if (!response) {
            //Check likes
            hasUserLiked();
        }
    });
```

Does `previousWinner(function (response) {` only work on web method calls?

Comment: I'm confused. `previousWinner()` does not take an argument, so how can you pass it a function? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want use the return to determine if I want to call `hasUserLiked();`

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here.  The javascript you provided also has syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should define previousWinner where 'code' is some boolean that tells you to run the callback.

```
function previousWinner(callback) {
    //Webservice call
    services.isUserAWinner(ID, events, function (response) {
        //Code
        var code = response == true; // if response is a boolean this will work, otherwise you need to run some other type of conditional 
        if (code && callback) {
            callback(response);
            //Return
            return true;
        }
        //Return
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction, but where does `code` get set?

Comment: Hmm I added an edit that explained that but it didn't show up.  I'll add it again.

Answer (score 0):

The second sample is passing a reference to the function itself instead of the result. If you want to invoke it inline, you can do it like this:

```
  previousWinner((function (response) {
        alert(response);
        //Check to see if user is a winner
        if (!response) {
            //Check likes
            hasUserLiked();
        }
    })());
```

EDIT: And in cases "webmethods", by which I assume you mean AJAX calls, you are passing a reference to the function to be used as a callback when the request returns. That's what makes it asynchronous (the A in AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

from your `previousWinner` definition, the function takes no arguments, so either of the calls will be equivalent:

```
previousWinner();
previousWinner(1);
previousWinner(1,2,3,4,5,6);
previousWinner(function(){},function(){});
// and so on
```

It appears that you want to provide a callback as an argument in the second example.
If that's the case, you should consider redefining your function to something like :

```
function previousWinner(callback) {
    //Webservice call
    services.isUserAWinner(ID, events, function (response) {
            //Code
            if(typeof callback == 'function')
                callback(response);
            //return whatever you want
    });
}
```